# Second derivative multivariate functions

Tags: calculus

Without doing any calculation, explain why any critical point of the 
function

$$f(x, y, z) = \sin x \cdot \arctan(y − x) + \cos(y^2 − x^2)$$

is degenerate.

What I tried

I know that degenerate means that the critical point does not exists and the the determinant of the Hessian matrix is equals to 0. And that means either the function is not differentable or not continuous at all points.I think that it is because arctan(y − x) or $\cos(y^2 − x^2)$does not exists? But im unsure how to prove it just by looking at the function. Could anyone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Should there be a $z$ somewhere in there? Because as it is written, the right-hand side is only a function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: There is no z though on the right hand side although the function is suppose to be an f(x,y,z) function. From here u can tell that if u differentiate the function wrt z, the critical point will be 0 or the critical point does not exists.

Comment: Thats probably got something to do with the answer?

Comment: Well, what would the third row of the Hessian look like, considering there is no $z$?

Comment: It would be 0,0,0

Comment: Which means what, in terms of the rank of the Hessian?

Comment: One of the Eigenvector will be 0? The determinant of the Hessian will always be 0? Hence leading to a degenerate function?

Comment: It should be easy to see that any matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ can have a rank of at most 2. Which, for a square matrix of dimension 3 must imply...

Comment: The matrix does not exist and hence the function does not exists.

Comment: No, the matrix certainly exists. I just wrote it -- it's right there! But what property does the matrix have? Can you find an inverse of the matrix?

Comment: Okay thanks i got it , the matrix is singular and determinant is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there is no typo and that the function is invariant with respect to its third argument, $z$, then

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right) = 0.$$

This implies that the third row of the Hessian is all zeros, which means that the rank of the Hessian can be at most 2, which means that it must be singular, which means that it must have determinant zero.

Comment: Yup what i was thinking just now is that since the third row of the matrix was all zeros, if u try finding the determinant u surely have to multiply the third row which is zero, hence giving the determinant of 0. I didnt think in terms of rank or singularity though. I think straight away in terms of determinant

Comment: Rank, singularness, and determinants are all intricately-related concepts.